# .NET 5 Source Generators. How use also referenced assembly

Tags: c#, .net, .net-5, roslyn-code-analysis, compiler-generated

I try to use .NET 5 Source Generators for generate webapi controllers starting from commands and queries.

I use this article [example]https://www.edument.se/en/blog/post/net-5-source-generators-mediatr-cqrs for this

But i want use commands and queries classes in external project referenced assembly for generate controllers in webapi project but I don't understand how give instructions to syntax receiver for this.

The structure of my solution is:

Projects

> `SourceGenerator.csproj`
>
> > ```
> >    `MySourceGenerator.cs`
> > ```
>
> `Application.csproj`
>
> > ```
> >  Commands
> > ```
> >
> > > ```
> > >      `ExampleCommand.cs`
> > > ```
>
> `WebApi.csproj`
>
> > ```
> >    References
> > ```
> >
> > > ```
> > >       `SourceGenerator.csproj` (with OutputItemType="Analyzer")
> > >       `Application.csproj`
> > > ```
> >
> > ```
> >    Controllers
> > ```
> >
> > > ```
> > >       `VirtualExpectedGeneratedController.cs`
> > > ```

Comment: If the compiler does not compile these classes then you will not get them in the syntax tree.

Comment: See https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/discussions/47517 . Some bits of it are about ProjectReference, but other bits are about PackageReference

Comment: But what you could try is to create a class that simply holds one private static Property for all the query and command classes you want and then work with this information in the source generator

Comment: See also [this example](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-sdk/blob/0313c80ed950ac4f4eef11bb2e1c6d1009b328c4/samples/CSharp/SourceGenerators/SourceGeneratorSamples/SourceGeneratorSamples.csproj#L13-L30) linked from the discussion above

Comment: but if i have in my solution a project in .net5 how I can reference this? can I add only standard project?

Comment: See the linked https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/47087 . If you want your source generator to run with msbuild and Visual Studio, it needs to target netstandard2.0. Visual Studio and msbuild run on .NET Framework.

Comment: _"but if i have in my solution a project in .net5 how I can reference this? can I add only standard project?"_ please extend the question with information about: Solution-Structure, which project is the generator, dependency graph/list of the projects, which projects holds the classes that you are interested in using

Comment: @Ackdari I've added references in the web project to both, Generator and Application project. But I don't know how to make the SourceGenerator class to get the classes in the Application project